# Precision of the latest Michelson-Morley experiment in terms of speed of light difference?

Tags: special-relativity, optics, experimental-physics, speed-of-light

Here is the most precise Michelson-Morley experiment ever made:
[Laboratory Test of the Isotropy of Light Propagation at the 10^−17 Level](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.103.090401)

When they say:

> We find no evidence for an isotropy violation at a 1 σ uncertainty level of 0.6 parts in 10^17 (RMS) and 2 parts in 10^17 for seven of eight coefficients of the SME.

What do they mean in terms of precision of the speed of light difference?

Comment: The Michelson-Morley experiment does not measure the wavelength of light, so it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Well they were expecting a wavelength shift between 2 light rays, no? Which will result in some fringe.

Comment: No, the classic way of interpreting Michelson-Morely results is as a difference in the speeds of the waves in the two arms of the interferometers, not the wavelength.

Comment: Well if the wavelength changes then the speed will change as well. Here is the relation: ${v_2}=-\frac{\left( {{\lambda }_2}-{{\lambda }_1}\right)  {c_1}}{{{\lambda }_1}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are just saying that their measurement indicates that the speed of light is either perfectly isotropic or that any anisotropy is less than $0.6 \; 10^{-17}\;c$. This works out to about $1.8 \; nm/s$

Comment: Why are they saying in the following forum that it's around $1 \times 10^{-12} c$?
https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/very-precise-michelson-morley-experiments.836945/#post-5254075

Reference https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/very-precise-michelson-morley-experiments.836945/

Comment: @PhilBouchard That commenter is just wrong about the $10^{-12}$.  The experiment shows the fractional differences in the speed of light in different directions are at the $10^{-17}$ level or smaller.  That is what eq. (3) in the PRL paper indicates.